# How to send Email in Java without DB setting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, email

I have set up a simpleMailMessage service following the codes and information given from [spring-email from baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email)

After setting my configuration, maven dependency, and service, I am wondering How do I call the method without database source?

is it to create a controller to call this sending method from service in localhost:8080?

If I make my questions and situations unclear, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: Why would you need a database for this? What makes you think you do?

Comment: Link you provided doesn't use any database. Why did you get this confusion?

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new in programming.
Because my work project connected to DB, and I am now trying to build one on my own in another new project.
But after the setting the method, WHAT do I do to call the method to send email ? (Or what is my next step)

Comment: Seeing as no db is used there, as @M.Deinum already stated, the question has kind of answered itself

Comment: @mrHowareyou your next step would be to learn how to use spring(boot) and how to call it, but I think explaining all of that would be way too broad for SO

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, but my workplace is using a tool called scheduler to call methods.
But what if I try it on my own, do I build a controller instead?

Comment: You have to create a controller method and expose an REST endpoint (GET/POST based on your need) and call the email sending utility

Comment: Is REST/ controller things can be done without DB setting? (I have no idea at all)
Thank you very much

Comment: @mrHowareyou as already explained, there are no DB's involved in this story

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to **Server** as **DB**.

You do need a Server to handle RestAPI requests that send the actual email. But you definitely do not need a Database, unless you need to store some **data**.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much =]